# R - apply family function that uses same iterator for multiple variable

Tags: r, loops, apply, plyr

```
alply(df1 %>% as.matrix, 2, foo, keyword.count)
```

I have the above line of code that applies function 'foo' on each column of 'df1'. I want to add an additional parameter (df2) to function foo that has same number of columns as df1. something like

```
alply(df1 %>% as.matrix, 2, foo, df2 %>% as.matrix, keyword.count)
```

I want a function that uses same iterator for df1 and df2. In terms of loops, df1[1] and df2[1] in 1st iteration, df1[2] and df2[2] in 2nd iteration and so on. 
In current implementation using alply, df1[1] uses df2 matrix as a parameter and not a column of df2.

in terms of a loop, it would look something like this

```
for(int i=0; i<ncol(df1); i++){
 foo(df1[i], df2[i], keyword.count)
}
```

Is there an apply family function that allows me to do this? or some way to get the number of iteration that can be accessed in "foo".
Any help would be appreciated

example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
       col1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5]),
       col2 = sample(LETTERS[6:10])
   )
df2 <- data.frame(
  col1 = sample(LETTERS[11:13]),
  col2 = sample(LETTERS[14:16])
)


foo <- function(terms, fixed_terms , collocated_words ) {
  terms <- terms[terms != ""]
  fixed_terms <- fixed_terms[fixed_terms != ""]

##use terms and fixed_terms in another function

}

mlply(.data =  as.matrix(df1),  .fun =  foo, fixed_terms = as.matrix(df2), collocated_word=2)

##error:
##Error in (function (terms, fixed_terms, collocated_words)  : 
##  unused arguments (col1 = "B", col2 = "H")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mlply`:

```
mlply(as.matrix(df1), foo, argument2 = as.matrix(df2), 2)
```

you may need to specify what argument of `foo` each matrix is being called by

Comment: not quite. as alply allowed me to process my data frame by columns, mapply is applying foo to each element of the df1

Comment: looks like `mlply` should do the same thing compared to `alply` that `mapply` does compared to `sapply`. See my edit

Comment: thank you @tbradley. I'm getting an error trying to use mlply. it doesn't take the .margin parameter, so I'm trying to figure out a way around that. "Error in splitter_a(.data, .margins, .expand) : Invalid margin".

Comment: I'll prepare a reproducible example, if the error persists

Comment: mlply(.data =  as.matrix(df1),  .fun =  foo, argument2 = as.matrix(df2), argument3=keyword.count). results in error "unused arguments in function".  unused arguments are from df1. for some reason df1 doesn't map to argument1.

Comment: are you actually inputting `argument2 =` and `arguement3 =`? if so, that is probably you issue. You should put whatever the name of the arguments are for `foo`. I assume that `.data =` will take whatever the first argument for `foo` is

Comment: I'm inputting argument names. working on a reproducible example.

Comment: I edited the question to include a reproducible example of the error I get with mlply. This is the first time I've attempted to create a reproducible example. I hope it will work